# mysite is deleted and retention is for 30days. How to restore it from database?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, my-site, mysite

I had a situation here where an active user deleted his mysite and it was also not available under recycle as it is set to 30days.

We still have database backup and we got to know that the mysite is deleted after 4 months.

What is the best practice to restore that single mysite for an active user without disturbing existing content? I am ran out of solutions.

Comment: Get-spdeletedsites short name of mysite, run this command and check if it return the deleted site?

Answer (score 2):

**First,** The MySite site for a specific user is a subsite that can be restored using `Import and Export-SPWeb` cmdlet.

**Second,** it prefers to restore the `My site content database` to a test environment then export the deleted site and import it to the production.

**Steps:**

1. In the test environment, restore the My site content database using SQL Management studio.
2. Open CA > Content Database > Select the web application of my site, and set the current content database status to offline or dismount it!
3. Mount the Mysite restored content DB by clicking on '**Add content database**'
4. Run the [Export-SPWeb](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/export-spweb?view=sharepoint-ps) to the mysite URL that has been deleted from the production.
5. Go to the production environment, copy the exported CMP files.
6. Finally, import the exported site using [Import-SPWeb](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/import-spweb?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: Thanks a lot for these steps. Sorry I need to add on more line item, the tricky part is that we don't have UAT environment at all. Will there be any alternative solutions to restore the content directly to PROD?

Comment: You are welcome, Yes, you can do it on production but as we know it's not recommended to touch the production,  it's a risky process so I recommend taking backup first from the current my site DB then out working hour perform the above steps and make sure the restored DB has different name from the current one to can restore it or dismount it completely from its web application and remount the old DB then perform export, then dismount the old one and mount the current one then perform import!

Comment: Another safely option that will not require downtime is creating another my site host on the same farm on diffrent web app and apply the above steps!

Comment: hi Mohamed, with respect toi second option of creating another mysite host on diiferent webapp, which means I need to create an webapplication called ex: mysites1.domain.com and then attach the old DB and then do an export and then and I can import to existing working mysite webaaplication/site collection for that particular user mysite right? And ocne that is done, how can I tag the restored mysite to existing user?